# Sort TableView by date while using Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I want to sort my TableView by date. So that the newest entry is at the top.
In the CoreData Entity is a current date attribute. I have tried this, but nothing happened:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Body"];
    _body = [[moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil]mutableCopy];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date"
                                                                   ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    if (fetchedObjects == nil) {
        NSLog(@"View Failed! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
```

Thank you for answering!

Comment: What is the problem? Is it not working?

Comment: You need to set the resulting `NSArray` to your tableView as the data source.

Comment: What is your datasource for the table view? I think you need to take data from fetchedObjects array.

Comment: Did you check the `error` after fetchRequest execution? Also be sure that the `date` property is named correctly in the Body entity and you've assigned a value to it. Did you check the content of `fetchedObjects` array ? Also as long as you use `initWithEntityName:@"Body"` you don't need `NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Body"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:moc];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];`. And the last one check your tableView datasource, looks like you don't update it with the fetched objects

Comment: Sorry, i am new in Obj-C. My problem is not to receive the data. My problem is to order the cells. Maybe this screenshot helps to understand :) http://s1.directupload.net/images/140625/2i3nslme.png

Comment: As suggested in several comments, make sure you set the dataSource of your tableview to the result of the fetchrequest.

Comment: okay, how do I set the data source in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note the comments that i've made in the code. That should be working now.
Just a couple of notes:

> - It's good idea to read [Apple Naming Conventions Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html)
> - It's not good practice to get the MOC in this way, better way is to have a separate class that is Core Data Manager and handles all Core Data work.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Body"];

//    You're updating your datasource but before setting the sort descriptor to the fetchRequest
//    Remove this line it's redundant
//    _body = [[moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil]mutableCopy];


    //Note that ascenging should be NO if you want the newest one to be on the top
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date"
                                                                   ascending:NO];

    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    if (fetchedObjects == nil) {
        NSLog(@"View Failed! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }else{
        _body = [fetchedObjects mutableCopy];
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the `return self.body.count;` was set in `numberOfRowInSection`, i have add the `else self.body = fetchedObject`, but nothing changed...

Comment: I highly recommend that you read the docs on Apple's website and try to understand this. It is very essential for using tableviews.

Comment: I'm not sure that u're getting the whole picture correct... If you provide more code from your TableViewController i'll try to help you with more verbose instructions. Although you must follow the Koen's advice

Comment: I've also edited mine, so take a look and tell me if u still have troubles

Comment: Only one question, so I understand it. What effect has the  `_body = [fetchedObjects mutableCopy];` ?

Comment: `_body` is your datasource, from which you get data to populate the tableView (cause it's array better name will be `_bodies`). So initially this array will be empty. `[moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];` will make a request to Core Data and will return the sorted objects. So you should init `_bodies` with these fetched objects to be able to present the correct data in the tableView. `_body = [fetchedObjects mutableCopy];` this line makes this.